# How would I call a variable that is witihin a function that's declared in a loop

Tags: javascript, function, loops, settimeout

I am trying to use rainData in the second Loop but keep getting undefined - I believe this is due to rainData being defined within a setTimeout loopany ideas? I am also using p5 to load canvas elements

```
  var offset = 0;
  data.forEach(function(dataset) {
    setTimeout(function() {
      rainData = dataset;
      console.log(rainData);
    }, 2000 + offset);
    offset += 2000;
  });

  createCanvas(640, 360);
  //console.log(rainData);
  for (var i = 0; i < rainData; i++) {
    rainDrop[i] = new Drop();
  }
}
```

Comment: Move the loop inside the that callback. Or rather, only the `new Drop` part, as the `forEach` already does the looping. No, it is fundamentally impossible to immediately access the `rainData` that will be created many seconds in the future.

Comment: Thank you it works